# Empty IMG SRC trigger logout in IE

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, session, cookies

I'm developing a web system now, and have debugged a very strange bug just now.

First I describe the bug itself here.

**Problem:**

When visit `http://mysite/`, it redirects to login and do logout at once.

There is a page, which url is `/site.php?arg1=xxx&arg2=xxx` everything is well in chrome, but when I  use the ie8, after this page loaded, the account is logged out!

**Bug Location:**

After a long term of debugging, I found that the point which causing the problem is:

```
<img class="item_thumbnail" src="" />
```

If I remove this tag, everything become good.

---

So I'm wondering: when the `<img>` tag render, what's its behavior? Will it request the login page? But everything is in mass with ie.

What cause this problem? And what will ie an non-ie deal with the img-src?

Need your help!

Comment: Could you add some code with relevant logic and the part containing the `img` tag?

Comment: It might. Give it a src and see if it stops

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I removed the `src=""` and leave it <img with class="..."> and everthing goes fine. But I want to know what will the browser do in this case, why chrome didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, according to

[Empty image src can destroy your site](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/)

> - Internet Explorer makes a request to the directory in which the page
>     is located. For example, if you have a page running at
>     http://www.example.com/dir/mypage.htm that has one of these patterns,
>     IE makes a request to http://www.example.com/dir/ to fill in the
>     image.
> - Safari and Chrome make a request to the actual page itself. So
>     the page running at http://www.example.com/dir/mypage.htm results in a
>     second request to http://www.example.com/dir/mypage.htm to fill in the
>     image.

Hit F12 and look in the network tab to see.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you! Exactly what I want to know about!